# Async/await issue when passing query results to client modal in React

Tags: react-hooks, async-await

I currently have 2 ways of retrieving some data via a hook - one way works great, the other isn't working at all.

The way that works pulls the data from a pre-populated list:

```
import { courseList } from "../components/Course";


const formattedCourses = courseList.map((course) => ({
    label:course.label,
    abbr:course.abbr,
}));

const useCourses = () => {
    const getAll = () => formattedCourses;
    const getByAbbr = (value:string) => {
        return formattedCourses.find((item)=>item.abbr===value);
    }
    return {
        getAll,
        getByAbbr
    }
};

export default useCourses;
```

The other way goes to the database and gets the data:

```
import getCourses, { ICourseListingParams } from "../actions/getCourses";


const searchParams : ICourseListingParams={};

const useDefinedCourses = async () => {
    
    const courseList = await getCourses(searchParams);
    const formattedCourses = courseList.map((course) => ({
        label:course.type+' Year '+course.year,
        abbr:course.type,
    }));
    const getAll = () => formattedCourses;
    const getByAbbr = (value:string) => {
        return formattedCourses.find((item)=>item.abbr===value);
    }
    return {
        getAll,
        getByAbbr
    }
};

export default useDefinedCourses;
```

I then have an FC that uses that hook:

```
const DefinedCourseSelect:React.FC<CourseSelectProps> =  ({
    value,
    onChange
}) => {
    const { getAll} = useCourses();  **//async issue here if I go to useDefinedCourses**
```

This works great until I go to useDefinedCourses(), in which case I have to put in an await because it is async.

Once I put in await, I have to make the whole FC async.

```
const DefinedCourseSelect:React.FC<CourseSelectProps> =  async ({
    value,
    onChange
}) => {
    const { getAll} = await useDefinedCourses();
```

If I then use that DefinedCourseSelect in a Modal marked 'use client' it blows up with "Can't resolve fs"

I know I'm not handling the async call properly here - how can I change this so that the db-retrieved data in useDefinedCourses() hook can be used in a client component?

I tried removing the 'use client' (but that doesn't work, because I need to useState() on it later), and tried not doing the await at all and trying to parse the promise (which threw other errors).

Note, I did see several async/await React issues, but none that seemed to be how to pass from an async-retrieved dataset to a client component. It's possible I missed one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React wait for fetch data as part of custom hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822971/react-wait-for-fetch-data-as-part-of-custom-hook)

Comment: Ah! Actually, I think it might very well answer it. Let me try that out.

Comment: While I loved the accepted answer, I ended up doing something slightly different. I made an API endpoint to serve the result of my prisma query, and then in the hook used Axios to do a GET request on the endpoint, and then used useState to update the return value via the .finally call - I'm pretty sure this is the cleanest approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, even if it is basically a duplicate I'll help you a bit.

The issue - hooks should not be async. If you need to execute some async action inside of it - you need to use `useEffect` hook. This is the very basics of React, to be honest, so please, read a bit about the most common hooks aka `useState`, `useEffect`, `useCallback`, `useRef`, `useMemo`.

Next thing I'd like to point out - `const searchParams : ICourseListingParams={};` which I'd recommend to move to your custom hook argument. But here is a little pitfall, due to it is an `object`, not a primitive like number or string - calling it in a way `useDefinedCourses({ id: "112" });` will pass a new object with new reference on every rerender, but there is a fix for that. Without that fix - you will need to use `useState` or `useMemo` hook to preserve this object's reference between rerenders to be able to use it in a `depsArray`.

The fix itself (replace isEquals with any other function you'd like if you dont want to install lodash-es for it):

```js
import { isEqual } from "lodash-es";

export function useDeepCompare<T>(data: T) {
  const [memoized, setMemoized] = useState<T>(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMemoized((curr) => (isEqual(curr, data) ? curr : data));
  }, [data]);

  return memoized;
}
```

Now your modified hook (adjust it in a way you need):

```js
const useDefinedCourses = (searchParams?: ICourseListingParams) => {
  const memoizedSearchParams = useDeepCompare(searchParams);

  const [courses, setCourses] = useState<ICourse[] | undefined>(undefined);
  const formattedCourses = useMemo(() => {
    if (!courses) return [];
    return courses.map((course) => ({
      label: course.type + " Year " + course.year,
      abbr: course.type
    }));
  }, [courses]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // reset current state to initial
    setCourses(undefined);
    
    const ctrl = new AbortController();
    const fn = async () => {
      const courseList = await getCourses(memoizedSearchParams);
      // if hook arguments were changed before results are loaded - return
      if (ctrl && ctrl.signal.aborted) return;
      setCourses(courseList);
    };

    fn().catch(console.error);

    return () => {
      ctrl.abort();
    };
  }, [memoizedSearchParams]);

  const getByAbbr = (value: string) => {
    return formattedCourses.find((item) => item.abbr === value);
  };
  return {
    courses,
    formattedCourses,
    getByAbbr
  };
};
```

Notes about it:

1. Hook argument is optional, so you can call it with or without searchParams. Adjust it in a way you need.
2. `formattedCourses` are declared with `useMemo` hook. That way it will be calculated once the `courses` are loaded. You can replace this by some function to calculate and load it on-demand instead of in-place. You will be able to save some memory that way, if not all of your hook consumers will need this data.
3. AbortController is used to prevent state changes when searchParams argument is changed for scenarios when response from first async call is resolved after the 2nd async call. Happens sometimes.

Usage:

```js
const { formattedCourses } = useDefinedCourses({ id: "112" });
// or
const { formattedCourses } = useDefinedCourses();
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for this. Really appreciate it